# How do you create a virtualenv using python installed by pyenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv

I have 2 pyenv versions installed

```
pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7 (set by ../.python-version)
  3.5.3
```

when I am creating a `virtualenv` inside my project directory, I want it to create a `virtualenv` for the current `pyenv` python version `2.7`

but when i'm creating one using `mkvirtualenv whatever`

the virtual env is creating a python3 virtualenv

```
ll ~/.virtualenvs/mobile2/bin
total 5800
-rw-r--r--  1 ohadperry  staff   2.0K Sep  6 10:59 activate
-rw-r--r--  1 ohadperry  staff   1.0K Sep  6 10:59 activate.csh
-rw-r--r--  1 ohadperry  staff   2.1K Sep  6 10:59 activate.fish
-rw-r--r--  1 ohadperry  staff   1.1K Sep  6 10:59 activate_this.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff   266B Sep  6 10:59 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff   266B Sep  6 10:59 easy_install-3.5
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff   149B Sep  6 10:59 get_env_details
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff   238B Sep  6 10:59 pip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff   238B Sep  6 10:59 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff   238B Sep  6 10:59 pip3.5
-rw-r--r--  1 ohadperry  staff    71B Sep  6 10:59 postactivate
-rw-r--r--  1 ohadperry  staff    73B Sep  6 10:59 postdeactivate
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff    68B Sep  6 10:59 preactivate
-rw-r--r--  1 ohadperry  staff    74B Sep  6 10:59 predeactivate
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff   2.8M Sep  6 10:58 python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff   2.3K Sep  6 10:59 python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff     6B Sep  6 10:58 python3 -> python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff     6B Sep  6 10:58 python3.5 -> python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ohadperry  staff   245B Sep  6 10:59 wheel
```

Comment: Refer this ans, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: you are right. suggest to close this question

Comment: No, don't close it. This question is about using virtualenv in pyenv - the title should be updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for python2.7

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 my_env
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using `pyenv`, I would recommend building a `pyenv` controlled `virualenv` (make sure [`pyenv-virtualenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) is installed first)

```
$ pyenv virtualenv 2.7 <your new env>
```

Which you can then switch to this virtualenv using `pyenv`

```
$ pyenv local <your new env>
```

or

```
$ pyenv shell <your new env>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, and I believe the accepted answer doesn't reflect the question since it's been edited. I do believe my solution solves the stated problem as it is right now.

The original question was `how to create a virtualenv in selected python version explicitly`, for which Somil's answer is correct.

However, for those who wish to create a virtualenv using a python version installed by pyenv, here is my answer.

---

I was trying to create a virtualenv using `Python 3.6.9`, having `3.10.7` installed system-wide.
I had no luck using the system installed `virtualenv`. I tried `virtualenv -p ~/.pyenv/versions/<version>/bin/python env`, and although it creates the folders and scripts, it presented errors regarding wheel packages.

What worked was installing `virtualenv` from the `pyenv` installed version and using it to create the `env`.

1. Install the Python version you want:

```
$ pyenv install <version>
```

2. Select that version to run on your current shell

```
$ pyenv shell <version>
```

3. Install `virtualenv` using `pip` from that version

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
```

4. Use the installed `virtualenv` to create the `env`.

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 env
```